# Не работает редактирование на сервере

Tags: php

Работает удаление и добавление, а редактирование не работает пишет bool(false). Удаление и добавление делал так же, в чем может быть причина?

```
  public function upd($name, $surname, $group, $date_of_taking, $lib_card, $name_book, $id_lib) : array
    {
      $result = $this->mysqli->query("UPDATE info SET 
        name = '".$this->mysqli->escape_string($name)."', 
        surname = '".$this->mysqli->escape_string($surname)."', 
        group = '".$this->mysqli->escape_string($group)."', 
        date_of_taking = '".$this->mysqli->escape_string($date_of_taking)."', 
        lib_card = '".$this->mysqli->escape_string($lib_card)."', 
        name_book = '".$this->mysqli->escape_string($name_book)."' 
        WHERE id = '".$this->mysqli->escape_string($id_lib)."';"); 
      var_dump($result);
      return array();
    }
```

Comment: А что возвращает `$this->mysqli->error`?